# Key Phrase Extraction in solr

Tags: algorithm, solr, lucene

I want to implement the key phrase extraction(KEA) algorithm in apache solr to extract the important phrases from documents indexed and create a tag cloud from  the results returned after the query is executed.Can anyone please guide me through the process.Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr has an integration Module with [Apache UIMA](http://uima.apache.org/) called [SolrUIMA](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrUIMA).
It can help you enhance the metadata by extract keys phrases, identifying language, people and much more.

Comment: Thanks Jayendra i had come across these tools but im not quite sure whether these will work.Does these require any NLP processing,like training data and all.I am very new to these tools and this task hence not very familiar about implementing these...

Comment: Hi Jayendra I just checked out ApacheUIMA/SolrUIMA, it has an Alchemy API annotator component.But the thing is i need to purchase the AlchemyAPI key for using the webservice in my module.I want some open source and free implementation of this module.So if at all any other suggestions would be of great help....Thanks.....